# entityfieldquery, return several results

Tags: database

I want get several entries of database. Im a entityfieldquery novice and I misunderstand how I do for get several results who contain certain fields (here, the fields that interest me are : delta, field_top_value and field_top_revision).

[image]

By example, I try this code :

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
$query
    ->entityCondition('entity_id',$nid_device)
    ->entityCondition('entity_type','node');
$result = $query->execute();
dpm($result); //show just one only node...but I would like get the five entries, with field "delta, field_top_value and field_top_revision_id"
```

I "tried" to read the documentation, but my english reading isn't very good, and I don't find example for my case..

Thanks for help !

Comment: Is there any chance you can get someone who speaks English a bit better to help you re-phrase your question? It's really hard to understand what you're asking, but I'm almost positive there's an easy answer to this. Just need to know what you're asking exactly :)

Comment: sorry sorry x) with the entityfieldquery, I want get several results and no one only result (with my actually code) 
And I don't understand how I can select some field in my entityFieldQuery (I would like select "delta", "field_top_value" and "field_top_revision" in my case)

As you can see (the screenshoot), Ill get five results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you load data by **entityfieldquery()**, then it will return you everything in term of node.

1. Here entity_id from table and nid of node is same
2. vid parameter in node is same as revision_id in the table
3. delta specifies multiple value saved w.r.t a particular field e.g. a field **category** with table **field_data_field_category** has multiple values testcategory1 ,testcategory2.

Then it will saved in the database as delta 0 for testcategory1 and 1 for testcategory2.

And when it will be returned in node all values are assembled to show in the particular field w.r.t which it belongs in the form of array.

Also you can load the node data separately by node_load() function by passing entity_id/node id to load all data w.r.t that particular node in assembled mode.

Answer (score 1):

The table in your screenshot is a *field* table. It stores field data for entities, for both multiple and single cardinality fields.

When you use an `EntityFieldQuery`, you're querying for *entities*, not fields. It wouldn't make sense for you to receive data for anything else.

The connection you need to encourage your brain to make is that **the fields are attached to the entities**. So, if you want to know about multiple field values for a node, you just need to go and get them:

```
// Keep track of the delta, you mentioned you wanted it...
$delta = 0;
foreach (field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_foo') as $item) {
  $field_value = $item['value'];

  $delta++;
}
```

If that isn't what you're looking for, then `EntityFieldQuery` probably isn't the tool for the job. If that's the case, and you're using MySQL as the storage backend for fields, I'd recommend manually querying the `field_data_field_foo` table to get what you're after directly.

Comment: I don't think its a good solution because the delta maybe modify by differents ways (another module by example..)
So, I think the delta don't start all time at 0 =)

But maybe im wrong !

Comment: Yep, you're wrong ;) the delta always starts at zero, assuming the field API had been used correctly

Comment: the delta isn't the weight ? if I set a weight equal to -1 via the ui, the delta in database will equal to -1 no ?
it's just curiosity =)

Comment: Sure, if you change database values manually, but why would you be doing that? That's what the API is for, so you don't end up unintentionally introducing inconsistencies in the data...before they're saved, field elements are run through `_field_filter_items()` to filter out empty items. That function returns them with `array_values()`, effectively resetting the array keys to zero-based again, so you can count on the delta always starting at zero :)

Comment: @user2137454 I think Clive may have slightly misunderstood that question (unless it's me!). If you edit an entity with a multi-value field, click _Show weights_, and set a weight to -1, that value's delta _won't_ be -1 when saved to the DB. (Clive describes how that's done in his comment.)

Comment: @Andy Yeah I was trying to make that last statement cover both scenarios (editing through phpmyadmin and editing through the ui). If done through the UI the delta will always be zero-basd

Comment: @Clive I'm with you; there's a touch of ambiguity to _UI_ in a question that features a screenshot of phpMyAdmin and talks about editing entities!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is looking for a specific node with a specific nid. nid or entity_id is a unique key. Use different properties to query your entities.